# Combine Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two `queries` in knowing the in and out cache of a squid log

this is my 1st query

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3),count(resultstatuscode) from squid where resultstatuscode like '%MISS%' group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3);
```

and this one is my 2nd query

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3),count(resultstatuscode) from squid  group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3);
```

I just want to divide my 2nd `query` to  the 1st `query`

can somebody help me solve this problem?

Comment: i just this to happen 1stquery/2ndquery...both of those queries works fine but the problem is when i combine those two the result is ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution: join the two queries using the url substring, then you can calculate the ratio.

```
SELECT a.url, a.codecount / b.codecount AS percentage
FROM
(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3) AS url,
        COUNT(resultstatuscode) AS codecount
FROM squid 
WHERE resultstatuscode LIKE '%MISS%' 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3)) a
JOIN
(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3) AS url,
        COUNT(resultstatuscode) AS codecount
FROM squid
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3)) b
ON a.url = b.url
```

Alternative solution with only one subselect that "prepares" the data for the percentage calculation:

```
SELECT t.url, SUM(t.miss) / SUM(t.total) AS percentage
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3) AS url,
      CASE WHEN resultstatuscode LIKE '%MISS%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS miss
      1 AS total) t 
GROUP BY t.url
```